# How to preload a has_one through a has_many in Rails 5.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I am looking for a way to preload a has_one relation when it is through a has_many. I have 4 relevant models:

```
class Order
  has_many :line_items
  has_many :products, through: :line_items

  has_one :review
  has_many :review_items, through: :review
end

class Review
  belongs_to :order
  has_many :review_items
  has_many :products, through: :review_items
end

class ReviewItem
  belongs_to :review
  belongs_to :product

  has_one :order, through: :review
end

class LineItem
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :product

  has_one :review, through: :order

  # HERE IS RELATION IN QUESTION
  has_one :review_item, ->(product) { where(product_id: line_item. product_id, review: line_item.review) }, foreign_key: "product_id", primary_key: "product_id"

end
```

The question is how to preload the `review_item` on `LineItem` when fetching it through a `line_item` so I can do something like `Order.include(line_items: [:review_item]).where(user: user)`

Currently, I get the error

> The association scope `review_item` is instance dependent (the scope block takes an argument). Preloading instance dependent scopes is not supported.)

So, I'm looking for a way to have that `has_one` relationship, but not have to pass an instance when querying it.

The query *should* be simple, it is the same as doing

```
# in LineItem
  def review_item
    review.find_by(meal_id: self.meal_id)
  end
```

but obviously I cannot preload that.

I feel like there must be a way to write the `has_one` relation that does not take an instance of `LineItem`, but I am struggling to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Your relation has to take argument because you do not have direct relation between `LineItem` and `ReviewItem`.

Actually in the problem domain the customer is reviewing not the `Product` in general, but the actual product instance that was ordered and delivered to them (=`LineItem`), so it's logical to have:

```
class ReviewItem
  belongs_to :review
  belongs_to :line_item
  has_one :product, through: :line_item
  ...
end
```

Comment: Yes, this is the question :). I want to make a direct relation between the two, but without actually modifying the DB schema. Your suggestion is a good one, but I'm unable to do so in this case (the example I provided is modified for brevity). It feels to me that I should be able to make a direct relation, as I have two fields that create that connection without any trickery.